# calling SweetAlert2 inside Async method in VUE 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, sweetalert2

I tried to pops out sweetalert if failed to retreive data from server

I've imported sweet alert in main.js :

```js
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2'
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueSweetalert2)
app.mount('#app')
```

And inside the Table.vue components i tried to call swal but got an error says (undefined $this.swal) instead :

```html
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        let transactions = ref([])

        onMounted(() => {
            getTransactions()
        })

        async function getTransactions() {
            try {
                let { data } = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transactions')
                transactions.value = data.data
            } catch(e) {
                this.$swal('Something went wrong.')
            }
        }

        return {
            transactions
        } 

    }
}
</script>
```

Any suggestion how to solve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `this` as the component instance inside `setup()` because the component has not been created yet. There are other ways to get that `$swal` property.

`vue-sweetalert2` exposes SweetAlert via [`app.config.globalProperties.$swal`](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2/blob/ec5964f/packages/vue-sweetalert2/src/index.ts#L38) or as a [`provide`-ed `$swal` prop](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2/blob/ec5964f/packages/vue-sweetalert2/src/index.ts#L39).

A simple way to use it in the Composition API is through [`inject()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-inject):

```js
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        const swal = inject('$swal')

        async function getTransactions() {
            //...
            swal('Something went wrong.')
        }
    }
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-sweetalert2-demo?file=src/App.vue)

However, the `vue-sweetalert2` docs recommend using `sweetalert2` directly in this case:

> When using "Vue3: Composition API" it is better **not to use** this wrapper. It is more practical to call sweetalert2 directly.

You can use `sweetalert2` directly like this:

```js
import { onMounted, inject } from 'vue'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    async function getTransactions() {
      //...
      Swal.fire('Something went wrong.')
    }

    onMounted(() => getTransactions())
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-sweetalert2-demo-mxtktb?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 2):

In `main.js` file

```
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(VueSweetalert2);
window.Swal =  app.config.globalProperties.$swal;
app.mount("#app");
```

Use `Swal.fire()` inside COMPOSITION API

```
export default {
  setup() {
    function yourFunctionName() {
      Swal.fire('Hello !')
    }
  }
}
```